# Sustainsys SAML2 How to retrieve and RelayState?

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I have a Salesforce IdP initiated authentication and authentication works well, but now I need to use RelayState to navigate deeper into the .NET app.

I am using the [Sustainsys MVC](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Samples/SampleMvcApplication) library and cannot find an example how to
retrieve the RelayState parameter. The [Sustainsys documentation has only one mention of RelayState](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/config-elements/identity-providers.html?highlight=relaystate#attributes). How do I retrieve the RelayState URL parameter?

Comment: along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968073/reading-relaystate-from-a-samlresponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the property `IdentityProvider.RelayStateUsedAsReturnUrl` to true and the ReturnUrl will be used as the redirect Url after Idp-initiated sign on.